# I want to display only the name of the files in the current directory and sub-directores without the file extensions

Tags: command

..../here is the code, it shows the files but it added the extension .sh
I want to display them without the .sh

//

find -type f -name "*.sh" -printf "%f\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and it worked

See below my answer ... thank you!

```
find -type f -name ".sh" -not ".sh" -printf "%f\n" -Exclude *.sh
```

The `find -type f -name ".sh"` - these are files that I want to find
-Exclude *.sh => this part will exclude the files extension which is the .sh